# Apache Beam to BigQuery in batch, intermediary files, are they only generated in JSON

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm reading CSV files, transforming them before writing them to BigQuery through beam (2.1.0) in cloud Dataflow. The generated  intermediary files in GCS for Bq load jobs are JSON files. Is there a way to generate them in CSV rather than in JSON, which will consume less space and IO. And if there is a way to change that why the default is JSON not CSV
Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV does not support nested or repeated data in the schema, that's why Beam does not use it for BigQuery import. JSON and Avro formats support it, and it may be a good idea to change the implementation to use Avro (we already use Avro for exporting data from BigQuery). Feel free to file a JIRA at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM.

Comment: Thank you @jkff for your feedback. I created BEAM-2879 as you suggested and hope I didn't violate any rule while creating it :)

Comment: @jkff I'm currently struggling to export data from `BigQueryIO.read(...).fromQuery` to an Avro file. Do you have a hint, how to do that?